# Maintain constant velocity of objects after collision

Tags: box2d, box2dweb

I have several circles moving around. I set the `linearVelocity` of each circle. But when they collide, their velocities change. Sometimes, the vertical or horizontal or both components of the velocity become zero and the circle doesn't move.

I've the same coefficient of restitution for all the bodies, zero gravity and zero angular and linear damping.

However the radii of the circles change. There is a change in velocity when circles of equal radii collide too.